# Angular multiple apps on one domain

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have multiple separate angular5 apps and an Asp.Net core v2.0 Web Api

1. Web Frontend (Angular5) with routes home, products, contact, about us etc.
2. Web Backend with authentication (angular5) for crud operations of products, categories etc.
3. Web customer app (angular5) for customers to track their products and orders
4. Asp.Net core v2.0 web api that all those apps above sends http requests

What I want to do is:

deploy all those applications to the same domain (not sub domains).

for example

- example.com/ -> web frontend
- example.com/management -> web backend
- example.com/customer -> web customer app
- example.com/api -> asp.net core web api

first of all, is that possible?

and if it is, how to do.

any online course, document, blog post, clues and any keywords for googling also appreciated.

In angular world, community is confusing so I was almost forgot my little understanding of angular architecture.

Comment: Does the information in the docs help: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: exactly. thanks. I can see how silly my question is.

Comment: Personally, I don't think there are any silly questions ... Web development has gotten complex and SO should be the best source of help for hashing through those complexities. :-)

Comment: There are some issues as well with hosting angular on the root AND sub directory that i'm experiencing. SO this is a semi related and to know.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, if you have succeeded in deploying all the apps in the same domain, please guide me too

Answer (score 0):

In the *index.html* file change the `base` tag.